# SignedCms.CheckSignature() always fails when using a valid certificate

Tags: .net, cryptography, pkcs#7

I'm trying to use `SignedCms.CheckSignature` in .NET Framework 4.7.2 to validate a message I know is valid using a certificate I know is valid. I'm using the following code to do this:

```
    using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class VerifySignature {

        public static void Main(string [] args) {
            byte[] signature = FromHexString(secKey);
            byte[] certBytes = FromHexString(sCert);
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);
            var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection(certificate);
            var verifyCms = new SignedCms();
            verifyCms.Decode(signature);
            verifyCms.CheckSignature(collection, true);
        }

        // Disposable certificate + secKey
        private const string sCert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
        private const string secKey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

        private byte[] FromHexString(string hexString) {
            var bytes = new List<byte>();
            int by = 0;
            int hexDigits = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; ++i) {
                char c = hexString[i];
                if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
                    by = (by << 4) | (c - '0');
                    ++hexDigits;
                } else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') {
                    by = (by << 4) | (c - 'A' + 10);
                    ++hexDigits;
                }
                if (hexDigits == 2) {
                    bytes.Add((byte)by);
                    hexDigits = 0;
                }
            }
            return bytes.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

I have verified that the `X509Certificate2` is valid, and the `secKey` is correctly decoded. And yet, when I call `SignedCms.CheckSignature` I get an cryptographic exception with the message "The hash value is not correct."

Are my expectations that this code should work incorrect?

Comment: What happens if the certificate checking itself is disabled, i.e. when you use `verifyCms.CheckSignature(collection, false);`?

Comment: Your code uses a SHA-1 based signature verification, and SHA-1 is not secure anymore for signature applications. Furthermore, the 1024 bit DSA signature verification uses a key size that is considered too small nowadays, and an algorithm other than RSA. So there are multiple reasons why the signature verification might be disallowed. If that has anything to do with the specific error about the hash value... I don't know, my knowledge about .NET internals is lacking (and so is Microsofts documentation, so a search returned nada for me).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I'm forced to accept the SHA-1 certificate; it's being sent to me by an SAP system I have no control over. Perhaps more recent versions of SAP Hana are using better hash algorithms.

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace of the exception? Because otherwise I have to run the code and hope for the same exception (and I'm on Linux at the moment still)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CMS SignedData value from `secKey` is built with detached content, meaning it's just the signature.  The way you're trying to verify it, it is verifying that the signature applies to `new byte[0]`.

- `new byte[0]` has a SHA-1 hash of DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709
- The signature applies to content with a SHA-1 hash of 1A1A7B63F70EA93616A10297BA4D27FB9255753B
- Exception: The hash value is not correct.

You need to find the content, and change your document construction to

```
ContentInfo detachedData = new ContentInfo(data);
SignedCms verifyCms = new SignedCms(detachedData, detached: true);
// rest of code goes here.
```

Once the internal digest can be verified, the signature will successfully verify given the public key (based on some data manipulation within a debugger).