# SignedCms.CheckSignature with SAP certificate is failing

Tags: c#, digital-signature, pkcs#7, sap-basis

This is a follow-up of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977562/signedcms-checksignature-always-fails-when-using-a-valid-certificate).

I am writing an external server which gets called by a SAP-Server. The SAP-Server signs the URL with a certificate before it is transmitted. In a previous step the SAP-Server sent the certificate it will be using to sign the URL to my server. So my server has the certificate the SAP-Server is using for signing.

From the SAP-documentation I know the following.

1. The unsigned URL looks like this

   http://pswdf009:1080/ContentServer/ContentServer.dll?get&pVersion=0046&contRep=K1&docId=361A524A3ECB5459E0000800099245EC&accessMode=r&authId=pawdf054_BCE_26&expiration=19981104091537
2. The values of important QueryString-parameters are concatenated (in the same order they appear in the QueryString) to form the "message".
   For the given QueryString-Parameters

   ```
    ContRep = K1  
    DocId = 361A524A3ECB5459E0000800099245EC  
    AccessMode = r  
    AuthId = pawdf054_BCE_26  
    Expiration = 19981104091537
   ```

   the generated "message" looks like this:

   ```
    K1361A524A3ECB5459E0000800099245ECrpawdf054_BCE_2619981104091537
   ```
3. The "message" is used to calculate the hash from which the SecKey is calculated. SAP uses the Digital Signature Standard (DSS) to digitally sign the hash value according to PKCS#. The digital signature is appended to the querystring in a parameter with the name SecKey. The SecKey for the chosen procedure is about 500 bytes long. In the example from the SAP-documentation, the arbitary values 0x83, 0x70, 0x21, 0x42 are chosen for the secKey, for the sake of clarity.
4. The SecKey is base64 encoded and added to the URL.

   ```
    0x83, 0x70, 0x21, 0x42   gets to    "g3AhQg=="
   ```

   and the transferred URL looks like this

   http://pswdf009:1080/ContentServer/ContentServer.dll?get&pVersion=0046&contRep=K1&docId=361A524A3ECB5459E0000800099245EC&accessMode=r&authId=pawdf054_BCE_26&expiration=19981104091537&secKey=g3AhQg%3D%3D
5. When my server receives the URL I need to check the signature. I recreate the "message" by concatenating the QueryString-parameters the same way as it was described in point 2. (as it is described in the SAP-documentation)

   > SAP gives this Summary of Technical Information
   > Format of digital signature: PKCS#7 "signed data"
   > Public key procedure: DSS
   > Key length: 512 - 1024 bits
   > Public exponent: 2^16 + 1
   > Public key format: X.509 v3 certificate
   > MD (message digest) algorithm: MD5 or RIPEMD-160
   > The library for checking signatures can be obtained from SAP AG. Because the standard format PKCS#7 was used for the signature, other products can also be used for decoding.

   I receive an "The hash value is not correct"-Exception on line `cms.CheckSignature(certificates, true);`

   ```
    private void CheckSignature(string secKey, string message, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String(secKey);
        ContentInfo ci = new ContentInfo(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));
        SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(ci, true);
        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection(cert);
        cms.Decode(signature);
        try
        {
            cms.CheckSignature(certificates, true);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.ToString());
        }  
    }
   ```

Can anybody help, or knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So, you posted this [SAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_NETWEAVER_700/108edb8b6c531014b0ea9b2bb674adff/4d06496c0dd02136e10000000a42189e.html). Please explain how you calculate the hash code (`secKey`), i.e. show your code.

Comment: Actually I don't do any hash-calculation. From the documentation I don't know which hash-algorithm I should use. I am not an expert in SignedCms, and thought that SignedCms does the correct hash-calculation. Any hints which hash-alogrithms should be used?

Comment: Sorry, in fact `secKey` is calculated by SAP CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the above function CheckSignature works correct

BUT the second parameter 'message' has to be URL-encoded. Or to be more precise, when concatenating you must use the NOT-URL-DECODED queryString values. [with the same spelling (uppercase/lowercase) SAP uses]

```
ContRep = AA  
DocId = 53730C7E18661EDCB1F816798DAA18B2  
AccessMode = r  
AuthId = CN=NPL          (for concatenating 'CN%3DNPL' is used)
Expiration = 20220511173746
```

will become the message

> AA53730C7E18661EDCB1F816798DAA18B2rCN%3DNPL20220511173746

---